# How can I update multiple databases using Doctrine migrations?

Tags: doctrine, migration, doctrine-migrations

I have several databases that I need to apply migrations to. Is there a way to apply updates to all of them via Doctrine migrations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant to you, but you can find answeres here:
[Symfony Doctrine Migrations, how can I use multiple entity managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115881/symfony-doctrine-migrations-how-can-i-use-multiple-entity-managers)